# Removing rows from R data frame using the for loop with if statement

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

```
df <- data.frame(
 V1 = c(1,3,3,5,5,6),
 V2 = c(19,19,38,19,38,19),
 V3 = c(1,3,1,7,2,10)
)
```

How can I remove the rows where *V2* is an odd number **using the for loop with if statement**?

Comment: Why is it that you're so insistent on using a for loop with an if statement? R has many faster, cleaner and simpler ways to do this? It might help if you mentioned why you want that one specific method, rather than just asking how to do what you want to do

Comment: Hi @divibisan, I understand your comment. I asked to use this specific method because it is for my personal learning, not because it is more efficient.

Comment: Ok, that's a good reason. I was just curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use @Aleh answer, even if you want to use it with **for loop** and **if loop**

**Try this it will help:**

```
dt = data.frame()
for(i in 1:nrow(df) ) {

  if(df$V2[i] %% 2 == 0){

   dt <-  rbind(dt , df[i,]) 

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is good, you can make this in a single line...
Try this.

```
df[df$V2 %% 2 == 0,]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a dplyr solution:

```
df_filtered <- df %>% filter(V2 %% 2 == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need for loop, can do like this:

```
idx <- df$V2 %% 2 == 0
df[idx, ]
```